# Jupyter notebook to Book

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have not found a solid way to convert a collection of Juptyer notebooks to a book.  Does anybody have a link to a tool that produces nice looking latex output from the notebooks?  Alternatively, I don't understand how I would use the `nbconvert` templates to determine the latex output activity.

I am able to use ReadTheDocs and get a pdf, but I'd like something that I have control over with formatting, toc, etc.

Comment: The [Jupyter Book](https://jupyterbook.org/index.html) package provides a way of using Sphinx to build an interactive HTML textbook site from a collection of Jupyter notebooks. See also [Jupyter Book: GitHub Pages and Actions](https://jupyterbook.org/publish/gh-pages.html) for more information on how to publish books automatically from a Github repo using Github Actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ipypublish](https://github.com/chrisjsewell/ipypublish) might be what you're looking for. It has built-in tools for managing bibliographies and citations and it allows you to control how notebook content gets rendered using metadata.

If you aren't interested in the bibliographies and citations, I'm pretty sure you can implement everything ipypublish does with metadata in a custom jinja template. [This repo](https://github.com/t-makaro/nb_pdf_template) has some examples you can pull from, as well as [this article](http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook). I didn't really understand how any of the jinja templating worked until I read through the standard templates in `/Lib/site-packages/nbconvert/templates/latex`.

Comment: This is promising.  I am able to get single notebooks output, however, I'm having trouble with multiple `.ipynb` files in a directory being converted to a single object.  I've named a few notebooks sequentially `01-...ipynb`, `02-...ipynb`, etc.  Any ideas?  When I run: `nbpublish -f latex_ipypublish_all -pdf --pdf-debug .` I get nothing, but if I put any explicit file it works.

Comment: Does it work if you run it from one directory up and pass the name of the folder containing the notebooks as an argument?

Comment: Sure does.  You're the best!  Thanks so much.

Comment: @butterwagon i'm trying to edit some of the templates used by ipypublish. For instance, the title page. However, I have no idea where to go and fix them. Where would you go to find them?

Comment: @Sosi nbconvert stores templates in Lib/site-packages/nbconvert/templates. I would recommend against modifying those because you will lose your changes if you update nbconvert. Instead, consider extending one of those templates.